# Access 2007 query incorrectly returns zero records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a small database in Access that works well except for the following problem.  The database is designed correctly and any the other 100 queries I have work fine.  I'm trying to find the correct SQL to return the correct records.  There definitely are records that match the (((tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="infection" And (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="pressure sores")); part, but for some reason it returns nothing.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Person.PersonID, tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation
    FROM 
tblKentuckyCounties INNER JOIN 
(tblComorbidity INNER JOIN (Person INNER JOIN tblComorbidityPerson ON Person.PersonID = tblComorbidityPerson.personID) ON tblComorbidity.ID = tblComorbidityPerson.comorbidityFK) ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID = Person.County
    WHERE 
(((tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="infection" And (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="pressure sores"));
```

Comment: Could you give us some sample data where it should return something but does not?

Comment: sure, if the "And (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="pressure sores"));" is removed it returns about 100 records. if you change pressure sores in the above statement to "infection" it also returns roughly 100 records.  and although there are about 70 records that have both, none are returned.

Comment: You need to adjust this question to reflect you want a person who has both of these comorbidityexplanations.

Comment: As a side note: I think you're overdoing the parenthesis in the WHERE clause...

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL is trying to get all tblComorbidity records that have an explanation of "infection" AND "pressure sores". That's not possible, since ONE tblComorbidity record has only ONE explanation.

What (I guess that) you really want is to get all Persons for which ONE tblComorbidity record with explanation = "infection" exists and ANOTHER tblComorbidity record with explanation = "pressure sores" exists. That sounds similar, but it's something different, and it needs to be done differently.

Something like the following SQL should do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person.PersonID
  FROM ((((Person INNER JOIN tblComorbidityPerson AS InfPers ON Person.PersonID = InfPers.PersonID)
          INNER JOIN tblComorbidity AS Inf ON InfPers.comorbidityFK = Inf.ID)
         INNER JOIN  tblComorbidityPerson AS SorePers ON Person.PersonID = SorePers.PersonID)
        INNER JOIN tblComorbidity AS Sore ON SorePers.comorbidityFK = Sore.ID)
       INNER JOIN tblKentuckyCounties ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID = Person.County
 WHERE Inf.comorbidityexplanation = "infection"
   AND Sore.comorbidityexplanation = "pressure sores";
```

Basically, you need to join comorbidity twice (once for each explanation).

Comment: Aaaaah. THAT was what he wanted. I'm a little slow today ... good catch! +1

Comment: +1 internets :) that's what i was going for, but i didn't get it right.

Answer (score 3):

```
(((tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="infection" OR (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="pressure sores"));
```

You need an OR here, not an AND. `tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation` cannot be two different values at once.

Comment: this doesn't do exactly what i need.  i only need the records to be returned that have both "infection" and "pressure sores".  doing it that way will return records that do not have both "infection" and "pressure sores"

Comment: It's not possible. Your query can never return a result. A row cannot have 2 different values for the same column. Maybe you have another column called comorbidityexplanation in another table that is joined?

Comment: no, i don't have it set up that way. i suppose i should just run one query and the compare it to the other query.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

cularis is on the right track.  After your where clause, you need to add

```
GROUP BY Person.PersonID
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

This will group the records in the child tables by the person, and make sure the count is 2 (one for 'infection' and one for 'pressure sores').

Comment: +1, elegant alternative to the "multiple joins" variant. Note, however, that this COUNT-based solution only works if there is *at most one* "infection" record for each person (same for pressure sores).

Comment: @Heinzi - thank you for pointing that out, that is correct.  In my testing that was the case, but that is not definitely the case for the OP - that sql statement is more complex than what I tested with and I'm not sure of the OP's table structure.